# What is CSM option

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

What is the CSM option in BIOS? If I can't boot into Windows any more, is it because CSM is disabled?

Would an ASUS K55 come with this option diabled?

Comment: Are there any beep patterns or error leds flashing? CSM should be enabled for non-UEFI capable operating systems.

Comment: No, nothing. It shows no ASUS logo or Windows logo. My son may have changed something in BIOS to keep if from booting. It cant find the recovery partition so we cant do a restore. I dont know what the terms CSM or UEFI mean on a Windows 8 system

Comment: If you have a bit of time, I heavily recommend reading [this article](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) for a better understanding of just how UEFI works.

Comment: As for your actual question - firstly, did it work when you received the device? If not, get a replacement. If yes, then what was the last thing you changed before it stopped working?

Comment: Worked perfectly for 18 months, then booting became a multiple attempt thing until finally it quit altogether, just black screen. I managed to get into bios and see that fast boot and launch CSM are both disabled. I added a boot option for the cd drive and have a windows disc but it wont boot to the disc.

Comment: I skimmed most of the article you posted. Good but deeper than I need right now. I just reset all option to default settings and restarted, no effect.

Comment: @Ken I've removed the chunk about the not booting problem, limiting this information/question to just be your question(s) about CSM.  If this was actually an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174452), and you really wanted answers about your notebook not booting, then please start a new question that's actually about that, and not about suspected causes.

Answer (score 51):

[CSM or Compatibility Support Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) is something that allows booting in legacy BIOS mode on UEFI systems.

From Wikipedia:

> The Compatibility Support Module (CSM) is a component of the UEFI
>   firmware that provides legacy BIOS compatibility by emulating a BIOS
>   environment, allowing legacy operating systems and some option ROMs
>   that do not support UEFI to still be used.

Suffice it to say that if your PC is fairly new and came with Windows pre-installed, CSM would've been disabled by default. You don't need to enable it. It's only needed if you must install an older OS that doesn't support UEFI.

If you've mucked around in the BIOS settings, reset it to defaults and see if your PC boots again. Most BIOSes have a keyboard shortcut to reset to factory default settings. It's <kbd>F10</kbd> on my BIOS.

Comment: OS support for UEFI isn't the only reason to need CSM. Graphics cards from as recently as 2013 don't all support UEFI and require CSM to boot. BIOS updates for some (my GTX 680 received one such update from Asus) are available, but not for all cards.

Comment: @Vinayak, What does ""OS that doesn't support UEFI"" even mean? Isn't the UEFI a pre-OS thing? Why would the OS need to know about UEFI?

Comment: @Pacerier I was referring to Windows XP. To the best of my knowledge, you have to be in legacy mode to be able to install it because XP wouldn't have the right drivers to recognize the connected hard drive and would BSOD during setup.

Comment: OSs require interfaces to talk with hardware and firmware. W7 for example [won't boot](https://superuser.com/a/1174447/567466) without CSM. You can see [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/reference-guides/efi-compatibility-support-module-specification-v098.pdf) more about what this actually adds.

Comment: @Pacerier In UEFI-only mode, BIOS calls are disabled. Operating systems that only support BIOS will ask the BIOS about certain information and will use BIOS functions to do certain things that are required for bootup. UEFI replaces these and if you don't enable CSM, support for these things will be disabled and the OS will fail to boot. Another thing that CSM can provide is legacy graphics cards support (pre ~2014 cards) as well as PS/2 keyboard emulation so that the OS doesn't need to support USB to get keyboard input.

Answer (score 2):

From my "old school" point of view CSM is simply easier to use on UEFI machines.

When you install your OS you may have to pick between `CSM` or `UEFI`. The most important thing is you choose the option matching whatever is setup in your `BIOS` (Basic Input Output System).

Comment: BIOS and UEFI are not the same things - it's one or the other and CSM Mode is only available with UEFI. Enabling CSM Mode causes quantifiable performance degradation and should never be enabled _(even when this answer was written, there were only a few distros lacking EFI boot, with all gaining EFI boot by the end of 2017 - Windows has supported EFI boot since Win7)_. Post-2017, CSM Mode serves no practical purpose beyond booting to a legacy peripheral option ROM, and has already begun being phased out of UEFI by OEMs.