# Can't boot on windows 10, Windows Boot manager entry has disappeared from UEFI

Tags: boot, windows-10

After trying to install Qubes unsuccessfully I rebooted my computer and my boot entries were gone. Before I had `grub` and `Windows Boot` that I could boot on from the UEFI boot menu.

So I go to the windows command line from the installation CD and type `bootrec /rebuildbcd` or `/scanos` it says that `0 windows installations have been detected`. However the windows partition is still accessible and seems fine by all means, the windows folder is still there...

Other threads on this problem refer to things to do inside `C:\boot` but I don't have such a folder and thoses threads are on Windows 7 or Vista so does anyone have an idea on what I have to do ? Is there an equivalent of C:\Boot for windows 10 ? How do I restore the windows 10 boot ?

Answer (score 1):

`bcdboot.exe` can help creating/fixing boot files.

You boot installation/repair DVD/USB the UEFI way (eventually disable [CSM](https://superuser.com/questions/857117/what-is-csm-option) so you cannot boot non UEFI media).

Boot files for EFI/UEFI are on EFI System Partition on GPT style disks. Exact path for Windows - \EFI\Microsoft\Boot (and \EFI\Boot - fallback).

Select repair and open command console:

```
bcdboot C:\windows /s S:
```

where C: drive is mapped to Windows partition and S: drive is mapped to EFI System partition (ESP).

For mapping ESP you can use [`diskpart.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) or [`mountvol.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol). With diskpart, you can see what the drive letter mappings are using `list volume`.

**Note:** keep CSM (BIOS emulation) disabled unless you have to do something special so firmware allows boot only to UEFI media or GPT disk.

Comment: did it but unfortunately it won't create any new entry in the boot menu

Comment: You have to boot installation/recovery DVD/USB the UEFI way when fixing UEFI related issues.

Answer (score 0):

as root edit

```
/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

add this to the very end

```
insert this in the 40_custom section:
menuentry "Windows" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd0,msdos1'
chainloader +1
}
```

Comment: Does this change NVRAM?

Comment: I do not believe so. From my testing, it is persistent even after a hard reset.