# EFI Ubuntu not booting or shown in bios

Tags: boot, bios, acer-aspire, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-20.04

After having installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS, when starting my laptop it throws an error stating "No bootable device". When I enter the boot options menu by spamming F12 on startup, I find the "EFI device: Ubuntu" which makes the OS boot. However, when I open the BIOS by spamming F2, in the boot order menu, I can't find it. Any idea how I can make it the default boot drive anyway?

Laptop: Acer Aspire V3-571G

Operating System: Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop could be set to boot legacy instead of UEFI. In the boot options, see if you set it to only boot UEFI instead of Legacy (BIOS) or [CSM].([What is CSM option](https://superuser.com/questions/857117/what-is-csm-option))